# How to get a preview of camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I used that example to get preview from camera:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("JNIProcessor");
    }

    private final String TAG="LiveFeature";

    private Camera mCamera;
    private byte[] mVideoSource;

    private TextureView mTextureView;

    private String[] ResolutionList;
    private Menu AppMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_feature);


        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture pSurface,
            int pWidth, int pHeight) {
        // Ignored
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture pSurface) {
        // Ignored
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] pData, Camera pCamera) {
    }
}
```

It seems the Camera.PreviewCallback is deprecated and I should use android.hardware.camera2. The problem is I don't find preview callback function to get the raw data bytes.
I just want to grabe frame from camera without render it into a surface and to put it into a JNI function.

Comment: You can still use the *deprecated* hardware.Camera API; the new **camera2** API is more powerful, but does not work on older devices. At any rate, both the old and the new camera APIs (actually, the underlying Android developer guidelines) require that the camera preview be displayed on screen, i.e. rendered to some surface.

Comment: @AlexCohn Actually I was able to take photos without preview up to Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps to get a preview:

- Add camera permission in manifest file (Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
- Get camera instance with this method:

  ```
  public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
      Camera c = null;
      try {
          c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
          // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
      }
      return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
  }
  ```
- Create a class that extends SurfaceView and let the class implement SurfaceHolder.Callback and pass your Camera instance in its constructor. Get the holder in the constructor with `getHolder()`
- In method "surfaceCreated", set preview display and start preview

  `public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      try {
          mCameraSource.start(holder);
          mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
          setWillNotDraw(false);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
      }
  }`
- Stop preview and release camera when you don't need it anymore

  `mCamera.stopPreview();`
   `mCamera.release();`